# Activemq 5.14 start up on window7 failed

Tags: activemq-classic

Environment:

-window 7
 -activemq 5.14.0

I'm learning how to use activemq, follow the start guide, I use "bin\activemq start".Then I try to access http://0.0.0.0:8161,but the browser show me "The requested URL could not be retrieved".

activemq.log:

```
2016-08-10 22:47:36,170 | INFO  | Refreshing  org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@20e2cbe0: startup date [Wed Aug 10 22:47:36 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2016-08-10 22:47:37,964 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[D:\apache-activemq-5.14.0\bin\..\data\kahadb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 22:47:43,782 | INFO  | PListStore:[D:\apache-activemq-5.14.0\bin\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2016-08-10 22:47:43,970 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:Fung-PC-49294-1470840463814-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,016 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://Fung-PC:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,016 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,032 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://Fung-PC:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,048 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,063 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://Fung-PC:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,063 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,079 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://Fung-PC:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,079 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,344 | WARN  | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5717c37{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: / | org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,578 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://Fung-PC:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,578 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,594 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:Fung-PC-49294-1470840463814-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 22:47:44,594 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 22:47:45,592 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /admin | main
2016-08-10 22:47:45,764 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2016-08-10 22:47:45,779 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2016-08-10 22:47:45,857 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
2016-08-10 22:47:46,434 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /api | main
2016-08-10 22:47:46,887 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml | /api | main
2016-08-10 23:06:22,019 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@2a5ca609: startup date [Wed Aug 10 23:06:22 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,626 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[D:\apache-activemq-5.14.0\bin\..\data\kahadb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,735 | INFO  | KahaDB is version 6 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,767 | INFO  | Recovering from the journal @1:503 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,782 | INFO  | Recovery replayed 126 operations from the journal in 0.031 seconds. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,798 | INFO  | PListStore:[D:\apache-activemq-5.14.0\bin\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,935 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:Fung-PC-50031-1470841583813-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,982 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://Fung-PC:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,982 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,997 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://Fung-PC:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 23:06:23,997 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,013 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://Fung-PC:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,029 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,029 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://Fung-PC:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,044 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,263 | WARN  | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1fb19a0{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: / | org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,413 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://Fung-PC:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,421 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,427 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:Fung-PC-50031-1470841583813-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,430 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-10 23:06:24,938 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /admin | main
2016-08-10 23:06:25,265 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2016-08-10 23:06:25,265 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2016-08-10 23:06:25,343 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
2016-08-10 23:06:25,733 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /api | main
2016-08-10 23:06:25,920 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml | /api | main
2016-08-13 13:55:47,213 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@2a5ca609: startup date [Sat Aug 13 13:55:47 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2016-08-13 13:55:48,726 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[D:\apache-activemq-5.14.0\bin\..\data\kahadb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-13 13:55:49,569 | INFO  | KahaDB is version 6 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2016-08-13 13:55:49,631 | INFO  | Recovering from the journal @1:15972 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2016-08-13 13:55:49,631 | INFO  | Recovery replayed 35 operations from the journal in 0.047 seconds. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2016-08-13 13:55:49,678 | INFO  | PListStore:[D:\apache-activemq-5.14.0\bin\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2016-08-13 13:55:49,959 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:Fung-PC-53687-1471067749771-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,037 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://Fung-PC:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,052 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,099 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://Fung-PC:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,115 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,130 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://Fung-PC:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,146 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,161 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://Fung-PC:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,161 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-13 13:55:50,629 | WARN  | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1fb19a0{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: / | org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | main
2016-08-13 13:55:51,051 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://Fung-PC:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | main
2016-08-13 13:55:51,066 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2016-08-13 13:55:51,066 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:Fung-PC-53687-1471067749771-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-13 13:55:51,066 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2016-08-13 13:55:52,579 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /admin | main
2016-08-13 13:55:53,400 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2016-08-13 13:55:53,400 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2016-08-13 13:55:53,572 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
2016-08-13 13:55:54,508 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /api | main
2016-08-13 13:55:54,758 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml | /api | main
```

I don't know why it is not working, I do what the getting started guide tells me to do. Does not activemq 5.14 support window 7? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

As logged in your logs the broker was started and not failed, you must use http://localhost:8161/admin to access web-console as mentioned here http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html

Comment: I try as what you said,user http://localhost:8161/admin to access web-cnsole,but still failed.The gettting-started.html I had read again and nothing helpful found

Comment: I know why now,it must use 127.0.0.0 but not localhost or 0.0.0.0

Comment: Good news. Have fun